# Передать структуризированный интерфейс в качестве аргумента

Tags: golang, интерфейс

Как я могу передать `[]interface{}` (Структуру), чтоб пройтись по ней итерацией  и вернуть `v.Name` в качестве `string`.

Код:

```
type Win32_Process struct {
    Name string 
} 

func WmiQuery(intr []interface{}) string {
    query := wmi.CreateQuery(&intr, "")
    err := wmi.Query(query, &intr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, v := range intr {
        return v.Name
    }

    return ""
}

func main() {
    var p []Win32_Process
    WmiQuery(p)
}
```

Не получается так как не видит метода в интерфейсе, `v.Name undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`.

Comment: У пустого интерфейса нету ни свойств, ни методов. Если у вас есть коллекция, которая должна вернуть имена, то создайте непустой интерфейс для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Если наполнение `[]interface{}` точно не известно, то, пропуская неподходящие типы, так:

```
for _, v := range intr {
    if wp, ok := v.(*Win32Process); ok == true {
        return wp.Name
    }
}
```

Если точно известно, что `[]interface{}` может содержать только `*Win23Process`, то можно упростить до:

```
for _, v := range intr {
    return v.(*Win32Process).Name
}
```

Если тип может быть как `Win32Process` или `*Win32Process`, что маловероятно, то:

```
for _, v := range intr {
    switch wp := v.(type) {
    case *Win32Process:
        return wp.Name
    case Win32Process:
        return wp.Name
    }
}
```

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/WiS-hhdtr6b)

---

P.S.: следуя конвенции имён Go, не стоит употреблять подчёркивания в названиях, т.е. `Win32Process` вместо `Win32_Process`, если это зависит от Вас.